# WPF UserControl component editing by XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following code:
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RBSoft.WPF.RedConsoleViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="355" d:DesignWidth="691" Name="ConsoleUI_Control" KeyDown="ConsoleUI_Control_KeyDown">
    <Grid Name="_Layout">
        <Rectangle Name="BackgroundLayout">
            <!--...-->
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
public Rectangle IBackground
{
    get { return this.BackgroundLayout; }
    set { this.BackgroundLayout = value; }
}
```

What I'm tying to do is edit the rectangle (BackgroundLayout) from the XAML editor like so:

```
<Window x:Class="LifeEnvironment.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1064" Width="910"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:RBSoft.WPF;assembly=RBSoft.WPF"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <my:userControlTest>
            <my:userControlTest.IBackground>
                <Background ...>
            </my:userControlTest.IBackground>
        </my:userControlTest>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I have no access to this, what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do it, is by wrapping up the Rectangle with an User Control, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RBSoft.WPF.RedConsoleViewer" ...>
    <Grid Name="_Layout">
        <UserControl Name="BackgroundLayout">
            <Rectangle .../>
        </UserControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and then, change the `Content` property instead the object itself, so you don't lose the reference(`BackgroundLayout`):

```
public Rectangle IBackground
{
    get { return (Rectangle)this.BackgroundLayout.Content; }
    set { this.BackgroundLayout.Content = value; }
}
```

and finally, it will work:

```
<my:userControlTest>
    <my:userControlTest.IBackground>
        <Background ...>
    </my:userControlTest.IBackground>
</my:userControlTest>
```

Answer (score 0):

- in order to have access to control's property in XAML you need to make it a Dependency Property.
- i think (at least from what I have seen) a more common way to do what you're trying to do is to use a "common" style that controls the inner rectangle's background.

  **EDIT**

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IBackground", typeof(Rectangle), typeof(NameOfYourUserControl));
  public Rectangle IBackground
  {
      get { return (Rectangle)GetValue(IBackgroundProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IBackgroundProperty, value); }
  }
  ```

changing to dependency property will make your XAML compile, however, you still have to process it in your user control.

Also when you use it, you are trying to set the background to a property of type rectangle!
That clearly won't work. You must instantiate what your property is - a rectangle:

```
<my:userControlTest>
        <my:userControlTest.IBackground>
            <Rectangle  Fill="Orange"/>
        </my:userControlTest.IBackground>
    </my:userControlTest>
```

Comment: Not correct, a public property is perfectly accessible in XAML, and if the class implements INotifyPropertyChanged it can be used as a binding source. What it can't do is be used as a binding target.

Comment: Before -1, please, try to compile what you claim. Create a userControl and add a property, lets call say public bool IsDirty{..}, now when you instantiate in XAML :       <YouUserControl IsDirty=".."/> Can you use that property? does it compile? - No, and property changed has nothing to do with that..

Comment: I didn't do it before, but I did it just now, and it works perfectly fine, thanks. Well this isn't a `UserControl` for simplicity, but shows setting property also binding to it: `public class TestControl : TextBlock { public string Property { get; set; } }` `<local:TestControl Property="Blah" Text="{Binding Property, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />`

Comment: I think the main problem here is that the conversation is about the UserControl, which is a ContentControl or FrameworkElement. In you sample you are instantiating a simple class which is not the same.  Try you logic on any FrameworkElement and I am pretty sure it won't work.